# how do i submit data from a TextInput and reset the widget after submitting?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, textinput, kivymd

after using textinput data to start a new thread, the data doesn't reset and if i remove the data to introduce new data it also changes what is printing

.kv file

```
name: 'request'
MDTextField:
    id: emailrequest
    hint_text: "E-mail"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.70}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 300
    on_text_validate: root.calling()

MDTextField:
    id: seguridad
    hint_text: "At what age did you give your first kiss?"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.60}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 300
    on_text_validate: root.calling()

MDLabel:
    text: "Password request"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.80}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 500

MDRaisedButton:
    text: "Request"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.45}
    on_press: root.calling()
    
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: "Go back"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.85}
    on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
```

.py file

```
class Request(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super().__init__(**kw)

def calling(self):
    _thread.start_new_thread(self.imprimir, ("thread", 4))

def imprimir(self, thread, *args):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.imp2, 1 / 1)

def imp2(self, *args):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.pal)

def pal(self, *args):
    palabra = self.ids.emailrequest.text
    palabra2 = self.ids.seguridad.text
    print(palabra, palabra2)
pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Request(name='request'))

class work(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


work().run()
```

In kivy docs it mentions something about this and solving it by scheduling with Clock.schedule_once() but i don't know how to do it here

EDIT:
what i need to resolve is what appears in kivy docs in the warning section that says this:

Warning

When changing a TextInput property that requires re-drawing, e.g. modifying the text, the updates occur on the next clock cycle and not instantly. This might cause any changes to the TextInput that occur between the modification and the next cycle to be ignored, or to use previous values. For example, after a update to the text, changing the cursor in the same clock frame will move it using the previous text and will likely end up in an incorrect position. The solution is to schedule any updates to occur on the next clock cycle using schedule_once().

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand what ur trying to do with the code ? but i ll try to answer according to ur question.

lets say u have this in ur kv:

```
<ur_screen>
    TextInput:
        id: txt_input
        hint_text: 'filed for data' 
    Button:
       
        text: 'button'
        on_press: root.print_once()
```

in ur main:

```
data = ''
print_condition = False

def print_function():
    global data, print_condition
    while True:  (keep the thread alive)
        try:
            while print_condition == True:
               if data != '':
                   print(data)
                   data = ''
                   print_condition = False
        except:
          print('thread standing by')   
          # u can add a time sleep here

thread_print = threading.Thread(target = print_function)

class ur_screen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global data, print_condition
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def print_once(self): 
        global data, print_condition      #     use this if u want 
        data = self.ids.txt_input.text    #     to print once
        print_condition = True            #      without clock.shecdule
        self.ids.txt_input.text = ''      #        and keep ur threadalive

class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.ur_screen = ur_screen()
        screen = Screen(name = "ur_screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.ur_screen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()
    
    thread_print.start()
    threading.Thread(target = theapp.run())
```

*Another trick it might be useful*

lets say u have `Clock.schedule_intervale(self.update_data, 0.5)` u can stop it by `Clock.unschedule(self.update)` its better than `Clock.schedule_once()`   because u ll be handling the stop example bellow.
assuming we r using same kv file with a button and a text input:

```
### import what u need

data = ''
print_condition = False

def print_function():
    global data, print_condition
    while True:  (keep the thread alive)
        try:
            while print_condition == True:
               if data != '':
                   print(data)
                   data = ''
                   print_condition = False
        except:
          print('thread standing by')   
          # u can add a time sleep here

thread_print = threading.Thread(target = print_function)

class ur_screen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global data, print_condition
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        

    def print_once(self): 
        global data, print_condition
        Clock.schdule_interval(self.update_data, 0.5)       
        print_condition = True           
    
    def update_data(self, *args):
        data = self.ids.txt_input.text
        Clock.unschedule(self.update_data)  ## it  ran only once
                                            ##  assuming data != ''
                                            ##   also thread has printed once                    
class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.ur_screen = ur_screen()
        screen = Screen(name = "ur_screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.ur_screen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()

    thread_print.start()
    threading.Thread(target = theapp.run())
```

hope this was useful